# Ignore one parent when pulling a merge commit

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I want to pull a set of changesets from a certain branch in a remote repository. One of the changesets is a merge from another branch, which I don't want to pull. However, it will be pulled even if I specify the branch name:

```
hg pull -r REV -b mybranch REMOTE_REPO
```

Is there a way to pull this commit as a regular changeset, ignoring its other ancestors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is impossible. All changesets (whether they are regular or merge changesets) depend on their ancestors and cannot be pulled in isolation. This is a fundamental design decision in Mercurial.

Merging prematurely results in the annoying situation you describe — each branch is no longer clean and cannot be pulled without also pulling in other stuff. The best way to avoid this is to use [rebase](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) (if the development is local-only and thus elegible for rebasing) or to simply ask people to stop mixing unrelated things together until you can make a firm decision about what needs to be merged.